# How to add multiple module in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, package

In my case, I have just created a chat application in which one-to-one chat is done, and for group chat, I have cloned group chat from Github. so how can I merge the group chat project or module with one-to-one chat? any suggestions please be polite I'm new to flutter

[image: one-to-one module structure]

[image: group chat module structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong about your question, I would suggest.

1. Copy `lib/` files from group chat to a folder in your other app. Find a way to use it as a module on your current code.
2. Integrate the code from Github with yours, merging similar functions and classes then modifying the UI to yours. this is the better option though it's a hustle.